# mysql order by custom

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have four rows in DB table. I would like them to order by but in the below order

```
id
5
8
6
7
```

How do I go for this?

I can't take another column and set order there because DB table is not my custom table it is provided by the CMS plugin. So changing the structure of table is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT..
FROM...
WHERE...
Order By Field(ID,5,8,6,7)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11f48b/3)